# WSO2 ESB codings and design patterns principles

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any guide or links to know about principles of coding standards and design patterns about WSO2 ESB. Mean any standards to name apis, sequences, end points and etc

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide for Enterprise Integration Patterns[1], it basically has design patterns associated with WSO2 ESB. You can get a rough idea about standards and best practices as well

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Enterprise+Integration+Patterns+with+WSO2+ESB